# Plotting histogram by using igraph python package

Tags: python, igraph

I'm new to igraph package as well as python. I wanted to plot a histogram for degree distribution of a graph. Here's what i did:

```
plot(g.degree_distribution())              #here g is my graph object
```

My problem is that i'm not able to change the X-Y axis scale and also display them. I looked through the documentation but was not able to find the correct attribute for doing this.
Also i tried to display the X-Y axis label using

```
plot(g.degree_distribution(), xlab="Degree", ylab="No. Of AS")
```

but the labels don't show up. Can anyone please help to sought out this problem ?

Comment: have you considered using matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/) instead?  It has a lot more support for histograms.

Comment: The thing is i'm working on a project and we are supposed to use igraph package. Anyways i'll try using matplotlib. Thanks.

Comment: igraph's plotting capabilities are somewhat limited since there is no point in reinventing the wheel and Matplotlib is already perfectly capable of creating histograms (and many more). I would probably just take the output of `g.degree_distribution()` and pass that to Matplotlib's plotting functions.

Comment: Also note that `plot(..., xlab=..., ylab=...)` is not understood by the Python interface of igraph; you have probably found it somewhere in a webpage that deals with the R interface of igraph.

Comment: @Tamás How exactly would you do it on to matplotlib? I tried plt.hist() but it did not work?

Comment: @B_Furtado: what's wrong with `from pylab import hist; hist(g.degree())`?